# Unable to deploy to Azure Service Fabric from Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to connect to a secured cluster hosted in South India data center and I am able to deploy my application to the azure service fabric using Visual Studio but when I am trying to deploy my application from the powershell, I am getting the following error :

> WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact
>   Failover Manager Service... WARNING: Failed to contact Failover
>   Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM... False
>   Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : Could not ping any of the provided
>   Service Fabric gateway endpoints. At line:7 char:1
>   + Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint $endpoint
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricTransientException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster

**SCRIPT CMDLET**

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint $endpoint 
          -KeepAliveIntervalInSec 20 
          -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint $servthumbprint
          -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue  $Certthumbprint
          -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName cert:\CurrentUser\my
```

PS : I am passing the same values in the above cmdlets what I am using with Visual Studio.

Comment: Could you ping your endpoint, you could use telnet to test `telnet name.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com 19000`.

Comment: Maybe you could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/scripts/service-fabric-powershell-deploy-application).

Comment: I am unable to ping through telnet. I am getting the following error "Connecting To thiswillwok.southindia.cloudapp.azure.com:19080...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed". But VS is able to publish the application. Also, I used the same link for creating the script.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect at 19080 port? It needs to be 19000 unless you've changed it manually when you were deploying SF cluster.

Comment: That was a typo as I copied the URL from the explorer. I am trying with 19000 only.